# onkeyup event for checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, events, onkeyup

I have a simple situation here. lets face html code first =>

```
<form name="geoKey" method="post" action="index.php">
<fieldset class="gKey">
        <legend><input type="checkbox" name="checkUncheck" id="checkUncheck"></legend>
        <textarea name="txt" id="txt" cols="34" rows="5"></textarea>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

and here is javascript =>

```
function keyPress(e){
    var key;
    var box = document.getElementById("checkUncheck");
    if (window.event){
        key = event.keyCode;
    } else {
        key = e.which;
    }
    if (key==192){
        (box.checked) ? box.checked=false : box.checked=true;
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
    document.onkeyup = keyPress;
};
```

so , like you see guys when it is pressed key (numbered 192) checkbox is checking if it is not checked and otherwise too (this is everything working nicely) , but here is a issue => I want that if cursor is focused on textarea and pressed that key (192) in textarea doesn't write anything . please help , thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onkeydown` instead and prevent the default browser action by using [`e.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault):

```
function keyPress(e){
    var key;
    var box = document.getElementById("checkUncheck");
    if (window.event){
        key = event.keyCode;
    } else {
        key = e.which;
    }
    if (key==192){
        e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent default action
        (box.checked) ? box.checked=false : box.checked=true;
        return false;
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
    document.onkeydown = keyPress;
};
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Npy44/).

Comment: thanks man :), I thought preventDefault() function was only in jQuery lol

Comment: Use `console.log(key)` to determine which integer value gets sent. I'm sure that the code will differ in some browsers, as you're leaving the standard ASCII range (0-127).